# What is this flower?

Tags: species-identification, botany, flowers

I was in Germany recently, and I saw again a flower that I'd only ever encountered before at Meijer Gardens. It's interesting to me because I'd never seen a flower with color variation in only the 'interior' petals. Try as I might, however, I can't seem to find it anywhere! Can anyone tell me what this is? I'd like to be able to learn more about it.[image: ,]

Comment: Are you asking about the violet flower or the white/pink one?

Comment: For the violet/purple I would guess it is some variety of petunia. (Sorry, I wanted to edit my comment but that guess came 1 minute too late to do so.)

Comment: The white/pink one, I probably should have made that more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [*Verbena hybrida*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbena) Voss (See [here](https://quebecvert.wordpress.com/2011/09/27/de%CC%81voilement-officiel-des-exceptionnelles%C2%AE-2012/); the page is in French though).

[image]

It belongs to verbena genus in the family Verbenaceae. It's about 10 to 50 centimeters tall with a squarish stem and opposite leaves.The flowers are small with five petals, and borne in dense spikes on the top. Verbena hybrida Voss is always used as ornamental plant. They are drought-sensitive, tolerating full to partial sun, and enjoy well-drained, average soils. It's always plant in warm and dry and sunny environment. About why a flower with two colors in one petal, it's because there are always two kinds of pigment in the petals. The pigments in different temperature and different acid alkaline environment present  different colors. When the flower is open, the acid-base property changed will lead to petals present different colors ([K. Yoshida et al., 2009](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19521056)).

Comment: What is meant by *Voss*. Is it a subspecies?

Comment: It is the authority of Verbena hybrida. In Linnaean binomial system of nomenclature, authority name adds after plant name. But sometimes, Verbena hybrida is all the same.